# Replacing Text with RegEx and jQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery, regex

I have code that looks like so:

```
<li class="capture-details">
  Special Instructions
   <br>
<textarea id="catProdInstructions_6795606" class="productTextarea"></textarea>
</li>
```

Everything inside the `li` tag is generated by my CMS and I would like to remove the words `Special Instructions` but leave the code after this alone.

I tried this:

```
var text = $('.capture-details').text().replace(/Special Instructions/, 'Your Personalized Message');
$('.capture-details').text(text);
```

but this removed the `textarea` as well. I then tried:

```
$('.capture-details').prepend(text);
```

but that didn't remove the words `Special Instructions`.

How would I remove the words `Special Instructions`?

[Here is a fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/fvR89/) of the above code.

Note: I could hard code the `textarea` into my JS but I want to avoid this because the `textarea` id and class may change but not the words `Special Instructions`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could just get the textNode and set it's value

```
$('.capture-details')[0].firstChild.nodeValue = 'Your Personalized Message'
```

[**FIDDLE**](http://jsfiddle.net/adeneo/fvR89/1/)

Comment: Be careful to test this in IE because sometimes IE will put a linefeed in the first text node by itself and the text you want would be in the 2nd text node.  You can't necessarily just assume your text is in the first text node.  You have to actually find which text node has your text in it if you're going to do it this way.

Comment: @jfriend00 - works just fine in IE, tested down to IE9 to make sure before I posted it.

Comment: I've had issues guessing which text node something is in.  I personally wouldn't write code that way.  There's no HTML spec that says it has to work the way you've written it.  Also, your jsFiddle doesn't have the newlines in it that the OP's HTML does which is part of what can cause the issue.  Maybe my history was only older versions of IE, buy it still doesn't seem like a safe assumption to me.

Comment: @jfriend00 - yup, IE8 had issues with creating empty textnodes for just about anything, major headache, but who uses IE8 anymore. Shouldn't be an issue in other browsers.

Answer (score 0):

```
$(function() {
    var el = $('.capture-details');
    el.html(el.html().replace(/Special Instructions/, 'Your Personalized Message'));
});
```